# Component Object model Invoke

Tags: automation, com, invoke

How i use INVOKE to call method of an application?
My method name is "importCase" and its input argument is a string that contain address of my Case in my computer I don't know how i should use Invoke to call this method and how import input argument of my method. my code is:

```
  ::CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("SGNSAutomation.SGNSApplication"), &clsid);
    IID iid;
     HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, 
  IID_IDispatch, (LPVOID*)&pWMPDispatch);
  IDispatch * pdisp = (IDispatch *)NULL;
  DISPID dispid;
   DISPPARAMS params = "E:\new library\university\final project 
                                documentation\GPNS project\net1.gpns";
  OLECHAR * Name = OLESTR("importCase");
 HRESULT hresult =pWMPDispatch->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, 
            &Name,1,LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,&dispid);
 hresult =pWMPDispatch->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 
                    DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, NULL, NULL,
                          NULL);  

_ASSERT(hr==S_OK);
```

I think my param definition is wrong but i don't know how define it?